# Flask AttributeError when unpickling a function

Tags: python, flask, pickle

I have a notebook file where I have dumped a model and a function named as `custom_pipeline()`

```
pickle.dump(custom_pipeline, open('custom_pipeline.pkl','wb'))
pickle.dump(model, open('model.pkl','wb'))
```

In my app.py file I am deserializing the model and the function as follows

```
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
custom_pipeline = pickle.load(open('custom_pipeline.pkl', 'rb'))
```

There is no error for unpickling the model file and the application runs successfully. But when I add the unpickling line for `custom_pipeline`, the following error is thrown:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'custom_pipeline' on <module '__main__' from flask_path>
```

I need to deserialize the function and call it with my input data from the app. I am new to flask and would like to know how to approach on using a custom function in the app file.

Comment: Pickle never stores code.  It has merely stored a reference to where the function was found (defined in your main module), and is expecting it to be found in exactly the same place when unpickling.

Comment: I have defined both the model and the function in the same notebook file. I am using flask for the first time and don't know how to even approach using a custom function in the app file like we use model objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot serialize functions unless they are wrapped around by a serializable class. If we directly want to, then `cloudpickle` allows to pickle functions.

```
import cloudpickle

cloudpickle.dump(custom_pipeline, open('custom_pipeline.pkl','wb'))
```

And then in the app file

```
import pickle
import cloudpickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
custom_pipeline = cloudpickle.load(open('custom_pipeline.pkl', 'rb'))
```